# SQL Calculate time between one row and the next one

Tags: mysql

I have a table clicks

```
click_id int
created datetime
```

Example data

```
1 2021-03-01 12:15:17
2 2021-03-01 12:15:21
3 2021-03-01 12:17:21
4 2021-03-01 13:17:59
```

**I want to select all clicks including the time difference (in seconds) between it and the soonest click afterwards**

Result needed:

```
1 - 2021-03-01 12:15:17 - 4
2 - 2021-03-01 12:15:21 - 120
3 - 2021-03-01 12:17:21 - 3602
4 - 2021-03-01 13:17:23 - null
```

Can this be achieved using MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `LEAD` with `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    click_id,
    created,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created, LEAD(created) OVER (ORDER BY created)) AS diff_sec
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY created;
```